# Adjust table's caption to top-left of the table in latex

Tags: tables, formatting, resize

I have this output:

[image]

**Problem**

I want to align the caption just on the top-left of the table itself.

Briefly, I want it to appear like the following:

[image]

**Tex Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
 
\begin{table}[h]
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false,
              labelsep=newline,skip=2pt,
              justification=raggedright}

\caption{Notations used in this paper}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\hline
Symbols & Description \\ 
  \hline \textit{$ \mathcal{D}$} & A \\
 \end{tabular}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is the output of the code:

[image]

Any idea of how to do it in LaTeX? Or links to sources which may help me further with this task.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still unclear, whether you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false,
              labelsep=newline,skip=2pt,
              justification=raggedright}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]% Note: restriction h does not mean "here and only here", but
                %       only "here if it fits and otherwise top".
  \centering 
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Notations used in this paper}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
      \hline
      Symbols & Description \\ 
      \hline \textit{$ \mathcal{D}$} & A \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: centered table with left aligned caption restricted to the table width]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false,
              labelsep=newline,skip=2pt,
              justification=raggedright}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]% Note: restriction h does not mean "here and only here", but
                %       only "here if it fits and otherwise top".
  \caption{Notations used in this paper}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
    \hline
    Symbols & Description \\ 
    \hline \textit{$ \mathcal{D}$} & A \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: left aligned table with left aligned caption]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false,
              labelsep=newline,skip=2pt,
              justification=raggedright}

\begin{document}
            
\begin{table}[h]% Note: restriction h does not mean "here and only here", but
                %       only "here if it fits and otherwise top".
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Notations used in this paper}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
      \hline
      Symbols & Description \\ 
      \hline \textit{$ \mathcal{D}$} & A \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: left aligned table with left aligned caption restricted to the table width]

Independent from what you want, I would suggest to also load [package `booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and use `\toprule`, `\midrule` and (additionally) `\bottomrule` instead of `\hline`. And if the *Description* column should have several lines of description, `tabularx` or `xltabular` could also be useful. And BTW: There are [package for creating list of symbols, acronyms etc.](https://ctan.org/topic/acronym).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and helpful  response. However, I used your proposed code and it shows the same results as mine. The \centering is needed to center the table and I need to output the caption in the top-left of the table itself not the page as it shown in the third figure ( in the question post).

Comment: for the code that use threeparttable package throws the following error: ! LaTeX Error: File `threeparttable.sty' not found.

Comment: @maniejutye So you should install the package. If you don't know how, ask a question if needed after searching for [installation topics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installing) relevant for your TeX distribution.

Comment: Thank you so much. When installing the package, it works perfectly as i want.